# Command to get count of zipped hdfs file without moving those files to local?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, unzip

I have bunch of big zipped(.bz2) file in hadoop/hdfs location and I dont have enough space to bring those in my local and get count, I am looking help to get command  to have count of those zipped file in hdfs liek we do in local linux wc -l ***.txt for all the same pattern of file.